# How do you add Application detailed information to display in the Dash?

Tags: 13.10, launcher, unity-dash

There is plenty of information about creating a launcher for the Unity Dash.  No problems there.  However when you right-click on an application, it is possible for the Dash to display much more detailed information about the program.

How can I do this with a custom launcher?  I have created several .desktop files and they work perfectly, but I have several very similar versions and want to be able to right-click and get more information about the specifics of each launcher.

**Is this possible in Ubuntu?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dash > preview takes/displays the info from the app's package info, specifically `Description:`

For a custom .desktop you could use a 1 line description via a `Comment=`line in the .desktop